# How do I retrieve the field data  associated with an entity, using EntityFieldQuery?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm still confused about the entity concept in Drupal 7.
I have a node type audio with an MP3 field. I'm able to use `EntityFieldQuery` to find all the  audio nodes, but I need the URL of the MP3, which is stored in the "file_managed" table, and I don't find a way to retrieve it.

This is what I have:

```
// Query audio nodes
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'audio')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$result = $query->execute();
```

There is no URL in the `$result` array. At least I can't find it there; I only get the fid.

Comment: I usually use EntityFieldQuery + entity_load to get data. However, I'm stuck in the API for querying specific entity fields. For instance if I want "Field A" from all 10,000 "Foo" entities I'd use EntityFieldQuery to get the entity_stub for the 10,000 records and do a entity_load (alot of values). Is there a better way to load only specific fields and not have the overhead of fully loading an entity. I could use db_select to get a SelectQuery object but this requires explicitly passing the table name and that seems to defeat the purpose of allowing entities to resides in separate DBs than the

Comment: Question seems related to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18093/get-only-some-fields-with-entityfieldquery

Answer (score 3):

When [EntityFieldQuery::count()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3acount/7) is not invoked, what returned from [EntityFieldQuery::execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3aexecute/7) is an array having the following structure:

```
[entity type] => array([entities])
```

```
[entity] => array([relevant ID] => [entity object])
```

The relevant ID is normally the entity ID, as in the query you reported. See [entity_create_stub_entity()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_create_stub_entity/7), and [entity_get_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7) to understand what information the entity object contains.

To get all the fields associated with the entity you are querying, you just need to execute the following code.

```php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'audio')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($result['node']);
}
```

Comment: OK, got that.
Maybe there is another way to get the related file uri with the help of the file id which I have in the node array?
Sorry, if my question sounds stupid, but I'm still a novice...

Comment: @krabbe You could query the table containing the field data, but I would not recommend doing that, at least for two reasons: the code would be dependent from the table structure, while using the Drupal API you would not have this problem, even passing to Drupal 8 or future releases; the structure of the table could be altered by another module, or the result of the `EntityFieldQuery` query could be altered from a module, and directly querying the field table you could get a different result.

Comment: @krabbe Once you have the fid, you can use http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_load/7 to load the file object which will contain the uri to the file.

Comment: @Berdir That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`EntityFieldQuery` doesn't allow for adding addition field data to the query result. You can load the entities afterwards. From the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3Aexecute/7):

```
$result = $query->execute();
$entities = entity_load($my_type, array_keys($result[$my_type]));
```

In the above example, `$mt_type` is your entity type (node).

Comment: To load the node is not the issue. Problem is the url of the mp3. It's not in the result of EntityFieldQuery. I only get an array inside the node called field_mp3 with the file id.

Comment: It is not supposed to be.EFQ *only* loads entity types and id's. To load the corresponding entities, you need to use entity_load() or one of the direct load functions like node_load() as googletorp wrote.

Comment: And is it possible to load only one field data, without to load entire node ?

Comment: @Fedir Anything is possible, but this is not something you want to do - It will be extremely hard to do, compared to node_load and sometimes doing node_load is more performance efficient (it can be cached) or it's just about the same load.