# Get only some fields with EntityFieldQuery?

Tags: 7, entities

Drupal 7 has very promising ORM-like system of queries with EntityFieldQuery.

Currently, I understand how to make selection of nodes, but the result doesn't contain any specific information, like fileds, I'm looking for.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
                        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'event')
                        ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
                        ->fieldCondition('field_date', 'value', array('2011-03-01', '2011-03-31'), 'BETWEEN')
                        ->fieldOrderBy('field_date', 'value', 'ASC')
                        ->execute();
```

So we need to load entire data of nodes, if we would like to get only values of one field, for example 'field_date' in current example.

```
$nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($entities['node']));
```

If there is a way to get the value of fields, instead to load full data of all nodes, as it provokes some memory overload.

```
$nodesFieldDates = ???
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great question!

[`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7)  is truly good stuff,  but if you *really* want to get serious, you have to override the class in a custom module and add whatever behavior you need done in there.

I don't know your exact intentions, but I have referred myself to [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130301230831/http://treehouseagency.com/blog/neil-hastings/2011/09/06/building-energygov-without-views) on the subject in the past.  Credits to Neil Hastings for this well written write-up.

Look for code examples a bit into the article for nice examples of overiding.

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Comment: Ok, I see ! So, probably, it's possible to redefine "EntityFieldQuery" "buildQuery" method, to alternate resulting fields. Probably, this could work.

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer for this! The Apache Solr module [extends the EntityFieldQuery class](https://github.com/AmazeeLabs/apachesolr_attachments/blob/7.x-1.4-amazee/apachesolr_attachments.module#L783) in order to make it happen. It adds a new method called addExtraField.

```
<?php
$query = new ApachesolrAttachmentsEntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'event')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_date', 'value', array('2011-03-01', '2011-03-31'), 'BETWEEN')
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_date', 'value', 'ASC')
  ->addExtraField('field_date', 'value', 'value')
  ->execute();
?>
```

If you don't have Apache Solr installed simply copy the code for extending that class.

Comment: Created a sandbox for this as the Apache Solr module had some drawbacks https://drupal.org/sandbox/mikeytown2/2209909

Comment: Upvoted this answer simply for the (currently sandbox) module created by mikeytown2 (thanks!)

Comment: The link in the answer doesn't seem to work. It says "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."

Comment: @mbomb007 https://github.com/AmazeeLabs/apachesolr_attachments/blob/7.x-1.4-amazee/apachesolr_attachments.module#L783

Updated the link

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to override anything or extend the class. You just need to use [`field_attach_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7) to attach the field you want to the results from the [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class.

See also [Loading Only One Field From An Entity or Node in Drupal 7](https://timonweb.com/posts/loading-only-one-field-from-an-entity-or-node-in-drupal-7/), a good article with examples on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still wanting to get Fields from a EFQ take a look at the [EFQ Extra Fields](https://drupal.org/project/efq_extra_field) module.

> Warning : This module abuses EntityFieldQuery to return data from your
>   database. It does not work with entities or any modules that build on
>   them.
>
> It allows you to use addField within an EntityFieldQueryExtraFields
>   object (extends EntityFieldQuery objects). Initially EntityFieldQuery
>   only gives you back the entity id, bundle and entity type. This module
>   adds an extra layer on top of that without doing some extra
>   entity_loads! Important if you want to work with massive amounts of
>   data and you want to reduce the sql queries. Since EFQ already queries
>   the database for this information, why not alter that query to also
>   give you some additional fields. This means that not a single extra
>   query will be performed to get that data.
>
> A word of caution, if you rely on some post-formatting/post-loading
>   that happens in entity_load or similar functions, this module won't
>   take care of that. You have to ensure the validity of the retrieved
>   data yourselves.

```
Example

Fetching the node title

$query = new EntityFieldQueryExtraFields();
  $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'my_bundle_type')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->addExtraField('field_myfield', value', value')
  ->addExtraField('field_mynodereffield', nid', nid')
  ->addExtraField('', 'title', 'title', 'node')
  ->fieldCondition('field_myfield', 'value', 'some_value_to_filter_on', '=')
  ->execute();
Possible combinations :
addExtraField($field_name, $column, $column_alias = NULL, $table = NULL)

field_name
Specify from which field the extra field should come. If it is from a base table, leave it empty and fill in the table argument

column
Specify the name of the column,

column_alias
Specify the alias of the column,

table
Optionally, add something like node or user here (the base table),
```

Comment: I've tried both this module (EFQ Extra Fields) and the (currently sandbox) module by mikeytown2 and the latter seemed much better (nicer to use, more sensible output) and also appears to be maintained a lot better than the former. mikeytown2 sandbox module is at https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mikeytown2/2209909.